# Predicate Logic : Ptah the Egyptian God

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

There is this problem in my book says:

"Ptah is an Egyptian God, and he is the father of all Egyptian gods. Therefore, he is the father of himself."

I see the premises as something like this:
$$\forall x[Gx \Rightarrow Fyx]$$
$$Gp$$

So, I try to do the following using universal specification:
$$Gp \Rightarrow Fpp$$

I just substitute $p$ for Ptah to both $x$ and $y$. But is it the right thing to do? And by using modus ponen, can we say that it is valid that Ptah is the father of himself??

Comment: You need $Gp$ for "Ptah is an Egyptian God" and $\forall x [Gx \to F(p,x)]$ for "Ptah is the Father of every Egyptian God". Then Instantiate the second with $p$ and use MP.

Comment: So instead of $F(y,x)$, we use $F(p,x)$. I see, thanks!